# Best GUI framework for Java

Tags: java, frameworks

I want to start a new project with Java;

In the past I used to start with Struts + Tiles; but tiles was very complicated; I don't know the latest version of Tiles;

I need your recommendations in details for a good GUI framework;

Thanks.

**Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24596/what-web-application-framework-for-java-is-recommended).**

Comment: This seems like an exact duplicate of [What Web Application Framework for Java is Recommended?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24596/what-web-application-framework-for-java-is-recommended)

Answer (score 2):

There is no "best" framework...
Indeed, "best" really depends on your needs, on your knwoledges (it can cost a lot of time to learn a new framework)...

Answer (score 2):

At first when I read GUI framework I thought you meant Swing or SWT but I see you mention struts so I guess you mean presentation framework.

I agree that Tapestry is very good, but there are several others that are also quite good. Struts2, Stripes etc. Matt Raible has a very nice project going where he did all the initial integration work for several different technologies. It is quite easy to get up and running with struts+spring+hibernate or JSF or Tapestry and so on. He calls it [AppFuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home).

I use struts2 with spring and hibernate and sitemesh which was an AppFuse project to start with and it has served me well.

[Stripes](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Home) seems to be a great starting point for a Java web app too. I haven't used it as yet but I'm tempted.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like [Tapestry](http://tapestry.apache.org/). I've only used version 4.1 but development time is way faster than JSP or JSF. It allows you to simply refresh pages to immediately see the changes you made without doing a deployment and uses actual HTML for the templates/pages so you can preview them without deploying any code at all. There is a little bit of a learning curve up front but its well worth it. Version 5.0 is in its final beta with a release candidate due out soon but I haven't tried it yet. It's also got pretty good and easy AJAX built in.