# What is the main-stream Java alternative to ASP.NET / PHP

Tags: java, web-applications, frameworks

I've heard something and seen some examples of web application built using ASP.NET / PHP and I'm wondering what would be the equivalent way of doing similar things in Java world. Looking on the Wikipedia I have found a lot of frameworks and I'm kind of confused which one is the best.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The Java equivalent of [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) and ["Classic" ASP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages) would be [JSP (JavaServer Pages)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) with *scriptlets* (embedded raw Java code). *Scriptlets* are considered [poor practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202) in Java web development world. Taglibs and EL (Expression Language) should be preferred above *scriptlets*. The Java equivalent of [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) [(MVC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) would be a Java MVC framework. There are a lot of Java-based MVC frameworks out, mostly providing a Servlet/Filter-based controller and taglibs to interact with the model (usually a [Javabean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBean)) and the view (usually a JSP page, but XHTML is also possible).

To start, the [Java EE API](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/) provides [JSF (JavaServer Faces)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Faces) for this, which in turn comes along with XHTML based templated view technology known as [Facelets](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/tutorial/doc/giepx.html). Facelets is seen as a replacement of the good old JSP. Further, there are a lot of open source Java MVC frameworks which are built on top of the JSP/[Servlet API](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html) and which are intended as an *alternative/competition* to JSF. You can find little information of all of them [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/web-frameworks), the popular ones being [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html), [Struts2](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/index.html) and [Stripes](http://www.stripesframework.org/).

As to which one to choose, I suggest having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960280/what-to-learn-for-making-java-web-applications-in-java-ee-6/1960447#1960447) which I strongly agree.

Comment: And another +1 for this nice answer.

Comment: @BalusC According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801891/difference-between-request-mvc-and-component-mvc) it seems that ASP.NET MVC is a request (action) MVC framework, is that correct? (I assume that request/action and component-based are the two unique/main groups of MVC frameworks). BTW I'm also curious about which would be some PHP equivalents to these.

Comment: Please, share some experience on server hardware resources usage with GlassFish and JavaEE, compared to PHP or NodeJS. Java is often claimed to be very wasteful.

Answer (score 6):

The best is not necessarily the same as the most mainstream.  I think the most direct equivalent (thanks to its standards track nature) is JSF 2.0 & Facelets.

Having said that, there are reasons that the other frameworks exist... it's best to evaluate several and determine which one fits your team's style of development best.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24596/what-web-application-framework-for-java-is-recommended/24707#24707).