# what is diffrent between ASP.net and Spring or JSP?

Tags: java, asp.net, spring

I was ASP.net developer for a year.
and now I'm considering to change to Java web developer.
I was in charge of developing Front end like Html5, java script, Jquery, Ajax.
So I am supposed to study in institute about java. I wonder what is different Spring and ASP.net specifically in Web developing.

Thanks for reading it, Have a good day.

Comment: i think you mis-pasted your question in stack overflow instead of google sir. Since youre Trying to learn ill show you some links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371300/technical-differences-between-asp-net-and-java-servlets-jsp                         https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-HTML-ASP-Dot-NET-and-JSP

Comment: You will come to know when you are done with Spring. Have a good day.