# Is there something like ASP.NET web user controls in Java/struts/jsp

Tags: java, asp.net

In java/struts/jsp world, is there something like the ASP.NET custom user control, a piece of UI with back end code that performs a specific logic, and can be pulled and used in another place (for example something like the login control).

Answer (score 6):

The current Java EE API offers JSF 2.0 on Facelets for this. Note that Struts(2) is actually a competitor to JSF and that JSP is a view technology like ASP, not a MVC framework. As per Java EE 6 / JSF 2.0, JSP is been replaced by Facelets as the default view technology.

On top of the basic JSF implementation you can choose from a lot of "rich" component libraries which adds an extra CSS and Ajax sausage, for example [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) ([showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/index.xhtml)) and [OpenFaces](http://openfaces.org) ([showcase](http://openfaces.org/demo/overview/homepage.jsf)).

#### See also:

- [What is the mainstream Java alternative to ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556553/what-is-the-main-stream-java-alternative-to-asp-net-php/2556601#2556601)
- [What is the difference between JSP, Servlet and JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095397/what-is-the-difference-between-jsf-servlet-and-jsp)
- [Java EE 6 tutorial - chapters 4-10](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaph.html)
- [Coreservlets.com JSF 2.0 tutorial](http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/)

Answer (score 2):

What you are after is called [tag files](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnama.html) in JSP. I found that they are not as easy to learn and use as .NET user controls.

You can use them similarly to user controls .NET.

workflow is like this.

1. Create a tag file in web-inf/tags/AtillaTagLibrary/DropDownList.tag
2. reference your tag file in your jsp file like below

   ```
   <%@ taglib prefix="ct" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/AtillaTagLibrary"%>
   ```
3. Use your tag file like normal jsp tag.

   ```
   <ct:DropDownList  />
   ```

This tag files can get attribute values from outside like user controls.