# Switching from ASP.NET MVC to Java

Tags: java, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, spring, jsf

Last 8 months I have been working in ASP.NET MVC framework but now I have to switch to Java. So, I wonder what is Java's framework that is  the most similar to ASP.NET MVC. I would like to stick to MVC pattern but most of my colleagues work in JSF, which doesn't seem like (real) MVC. Which one would you suggest?

Comment: Related question: [Java alternative to ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556553/what-is-the-main-stream-java-alternative-to-asp-net-php/2556601#2556601). Please elaborate why JSF doesn't seem like real MVC. Your *actual* problem/answer is in there. @abarr: Struts is a very vintage framework. Not really worth the effort nowadays IMO. By the way, its inventor/creator Ed Burns left Apache and joined Sun about 7 years ago to create JSF. It's in essence a further evolution of Struts.

Comment: JSF, as I heard, is similar to ASP.NET Webforms (even has something like the VIEWSTATE - yuck..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ile,

unfortunately, i think you'll find that there's a huge amount of collaterol in JSF with your collegues. in my opinion, you'd be better to start off with JSF as you'll have a lot of knowledge that you can feed off of initially there. then you could investigate the alternatives and try to get some peer buy-in to some of your initiatives.

see: https://gmvc.dev.java.net/

so for now, suck and see i guess.

**[edit]** - spring seems popular as well http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework_%28Java%29

Answer (score 2):

Spring framework is really easy to grasp. I did the change the other way round and the concepts where similar. I suggest you get the book [Spring in action](http://www.manning.com/walls3/), because it explains the concepts in an easy to follow way.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say you stick with ASP.NET MVC because there is lot of investment going around it by Microsoft learning from previous technologies. Imagine they're now at version 3 in just 2 years span while JSF takes about 5yrs before another major release comes out.

And as a developer, you'll find yourself hanging with JSF because there is not too much people blogging about it. If there is, it would be old stuff already! Although, I have to admit I learned a lot with BalusC blog plus 2 JSF books. ASP.MVC had tons of books out.

But, ASP.NET MVC fails to compare with JSF in terms of FREE AJAX frameworks like JSF have primefaces and openfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Spring MVC have Model, View, and controller exactly like ASP.net MVC, you can use the Annotation for post or get data as you can do in ASP.net MVC

Answer (score 1):

Java Server Faces (JSF) is a java framework that looks like ASP.net MVC
Spring also is another alternative of java MVC