# what wrong with my java concept?

Tags: java, hibernate, apache-axis

here is my code(web service creating by axis2 ,generated by eclipse jboss tools)

```
public PlayerCalendar[] getCalendarByUseridArr(String userid){
    au.backpack.Calendar cal=new au.backpack.Calendar();
    PlayerCalendar[] arr=new PlayerCalendar[cal.getCalendarByUserid(userid).length];
    arr=cal.getCalendarByUserid(userid);//get the hibernate dao result
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            //i want to create new Url value
        String url=arr[i].getUrl()+"?eventid="+arr[i].getEventid();
        arr[i].setUrl(url);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

and here is my dao function

```
public  PlayerCalendar[] getCalendarByUserid(String userid){
    Session session = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    List<PlayerCalendar> list =session.createQuery("from PlayerCalendar where userid='"+userid+"'").list();
    int listlen=1;
    if(list.size()>1)
        listlen=list.size();
    PlayerCalendar [] sr = new PlayerCalendar[listlen];
    return list.toArray(sr);
}
```

it's work in my xml web service page (Axis2),

THE URL value like :

> user_calendarEvent.jsp?eventid=1

but when i refresh the page approximately 5~9 times

it starts to append more "?eventid=1" :

> user_calendarEvent.jsp?eventid=1?eventid=1

and after starts to append,
every times i refresh it , it always append "eventid=1"

> user_calendarEvent.jsp?eventid=1?eventid=1?eventid=1

but the true value just

> user_calendarEvent.jsp?eventid=1

where it wrong ?

thanks~

Comment: are you checking for isPostBack before calling the function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245188/asp-net-page-ispostback-equivalent-in-jsp-java

Comment: Maybe you are calling the method multiple times.

Comment: Why are you instantiating the array: `PlayerCalendar[] arr=new PlayerCalendar[cal.getCalendarByUserid(userid).length];` when you just re-assign it on next instruction :`arr=cal.getCalendarByUserid(userid);`:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't close Hibernate Session, so your `PlayerCalendar` instances remain attached to session, then you modify their `url` property by calling

```
String url=arr[i].getUrl()+"?eventid="+arr[i].getEventid();
arr[i].setUrl(url);
```

so hibernate updates the entity on each request (and concats `?eventid=...` to it).

So it is normal to have a URL with multiple `?eventId=...`s.