# How to a create editable data grid in MVC2 architecture in J2EE/JSP

Tags: java, jsp, datagrid, jakarta-ee

Can anyone provide me some links or examples how to make an editable data grid in JSP. I am using Eclipse, JBoss AS and MS SQL. I have tried my best to search for a data grid example in JSP, but most of them are not in MVC2 architecture.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a MVC framework. JSP is not a MVC framework, but it is usually been used as the "View" part of a Java based MVC framework. Although since Java EE 6 it has been succeeded by Facelets. As per your question history, you're coming from C#/ASP.NET world. The Java EE counterpart of ASP.NET MVC is JSF (JavaServer Faces). It has however competition, like Spring MVC, Struts2, Wicket, Echo, etc.

Since you seem to be just starting/hobbying, I don't expect that you're really using the vintage J2EE which was 5 years ago been upgraded to Java EE 5. Now, since december 2009 there is already Java EE 6 which provides JSF 2.0 out the box as component based MVC framework. It's unclear which JBoss server version you're using, but the currently latest JBoss AS 6 is a Java EE 6 applicationserver. It ships with JSF 2.0 as well. You can find a complete example of a simple JSF 2.0 CRUD form in [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html#ReallySimpleCRUD).

#### See also:

- [What is the difference between JSP, Servlet and JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095397/what-is-the-difference-between-jsf-servlet-and-jsp)
- [What is the main stream Java alternative to ASP.NET/PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556553/what-is-the-main-stream-java-alternative-to-asp-net-php)
- [What components are MVC in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104094/what-components-are-mvc-in-jsf-mvc-framework)