# Dynamic web page built in jsp to any advance java framework

Tags: java, ajax, model-view-controller, jsf, jakarta-ee

I am new in java web development.

I have a dynamic jsp page(Loan Application form) this also uses ajax to load dependable dropdown parameters and for validations.

**i got task to migrate this Dynamic web(jsp) page to any advance java framework.**

Please suggest which could be the best option for me to do so ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Java Server Faces. This is more convenient to migrate JSP developer.Check these link

- [JavaServer Faces Technology](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/javaserverfaces-139869.html)
- [JavaServer Faces Community](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/)

JSF has many resources and easily to use together with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

As per latest Java EE specification JSP is being replaced with [XHTML](http://dev.fyicenter.com/faq/xhtml/Tools-for-Viewing-XHTML-Documents.html). So, I would suggest use XHTML.

Comment: XHTML is not a Java Framework.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: My understanding on OP question is, he/she want replacement for JSP, which is XHTML. Reason behind my understanding is JSP also not framework. If that is not what OP meant, I am happy to remove my answer.

Comment: First, check what [XHTML](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xhtml/info) means. After that, suggest an MVC framework like OP asks: "i got task to migrate this Dynamic web(jsp) page to any advance java framework.".

Comment: Also, the JSP successor is not XHTML but [Facelets](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/facelets/info)

Comment: I agree on Facelets as successor which is built on XHTML, not just HTML syntax. So, I used XHTML term. May be Facelets correct term. Suggesting MVC framework is not simple answer. Based on 'n' condition choice may differ. Just listing all frameworks isn't enough.

Comment: That's why I've posted another questions talking about similar scenarios, and 2 experts recommend learning the basic and standard stuff, by now, JSF 2 + Facelets, that's what my answer points to.

Comment: JSP itself is not really being replaced with either Facelets or xhtml. Instead, for usage with JSF, JSP is deprecated and had been replaced with Facelets. Standalone JSP is still an active spec and nothing in the overall Java EE spec hints at being deprecated, pruned or made optional anytime soon. (I would recommend JSF with Facelets for nearly every situation though, but that's another story)

Answer (score 0):

There are many Java frameworks available http://java-source.net/open-source/web-frameworks, http://orangeslate.com/2007/11/27/six-best-web-frameworks-in-java/

Google for more. Struts and Spring are two of most acceptable frameworks in Industry.

Answer (score 0):

For newcomers, the best thing to learn might be Oracle Java standard as defined in [The Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/), where explains the basics to work with [JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) 2 and Facelets. Yes, there are more Java MVC frameworks like:

- [Struts](http://struts.apache.org/)
- [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/)
- [Play!](http://www.playframework.org/)
- [Google Web Toolkit (GWT)](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/)
- [Tapestry](http://tapestry.apache.org/)

And more. For more references about my answer, see:

- [What is the main-stream Java alternative to ASP.NET / PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2556601/1065197)
- [Java web development, what skills do I need?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1958854/1065197)
- [What to learn for making Java web applications in Java EE 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1960447/1065197) (off topic: this is my favorite amongs other answers).

Answer (score 0):

use spring and hibernate.Spring is high performing and easily testable.Its also easy for a beginner to learn.Hibernate is an ORM - Object Relational Mapping.That is using hibernate you can create a "virtual" object Database which can be manipulated within the programming language itself.Its also easy to learn.

Use

Java  --- Backend
JSP,Jquery                  --- Frontend
Database                    --- mysql

:)