# Asp.net MVC scaffolding like feature in Java servlet

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jsp, servlets

With ASP.net MVC 3.0 and visual studio 2010 I can generate views easily by selecting the Controller action ( right click + scaffolding ), so I select the type of View (details,list,edit...) and I can even select the Entity/List that the view will use as datasource.

The questions is: Is there such thing working with Java JSP and servlet with eclipse where I don't have to manually change web.xml?

Answer (score 1):

There's something wrong here. Comparing ASP.NET MVC with JSP/Servlets is really like comparing apples with oranges. [ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/asp.net-mvc/info) is a fullworthy component based MVC framework, but [JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) is a barebones view technology and [Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet/info) is just a barebones HTTP controller API. There is absolutely no means of a comparable component based MVC framework here with JSP/Servlet.

You need to look for a component based MVC framework in Java side. From the standard Java EE API, [JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) is been offered.

However, as to the tooling, there are as far as I know no "Scaffolding" plugins for JSF available in Eclipse which does bottom-top code generation all the way from DB until with the JSF view. Closest what you can get in Eclipse is generating JPA entities from DB, but it stops here.

Netbeans has a [JSF CRUD generator](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-crud.html) though.

#### See also:

- [What is the difference between JSF, Servlet and JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095397/what-is-the-difference-between-jsf-servlet-and-jsp)
- [What is the main-stream Java alternative to ASP.NET / PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556553/what-is-the-main-stream-java-alternative-to-asp-net-php)
- [Recommended JSF 2.0 CRUD frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180400/recommended-jsf-2-0-crud-frameworks)