# Comparison of Java web framework usage, especially in enterprise projects

Tags: java, web-frameworks

I'm trying to get a sense of what are the most commonly-used Java web frameworks, with a focus on large, enterprisey projects. I'm interested in which one is most favored by companies/enterprises (which may not be the same as the one most favored by developers or the open source community I guess). I'd also like to be able to cite specific projects used by each framework, preferably big-ticket or well-known ones.

Anyone have any idea about this stuff or can point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24596/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-assorted-java-web-frameworks

Comment: @SimonJ thanks, that's a bit helpful but (a) it's out of date (posted Aug 08) and (b) doesnt have the information on enterprise usage I'm looking for

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what you would like to do.. I would recommand to be familliar with: 
- Hibernate 
- Spring 
- Apache Camel (high value) 
- Apache ServiceMix (esb side) 
And a good knowledge about servlet (EJB, ...) and JSPs.

I'm sure other will come with better ideas but that's what we are looking for when browsing the dev's CV.

Last thing: Do what you love to do, that'll be the best framework ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not looking for a recommendation on what to use. As the question title implies, I'm looking for a comparison of web framework usage in enterprises.